# How to disable load images in WebView except certain image?

Tags: android, android-webview, webviewclient

I want to prevent `WebView` from loading images except certain image that starts with specific URL.

How to?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This is what you need to do -

```
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url){
        if(url.contains("dummyURL"){ // put a string that is common in urls that you want to load
        }else {
            view.stopLoading();
        }            
        return false;
    }  
});
```